# CakePHP 3: Setting a variable in a Listener

Tags: cakephp

Is it possible to set a variable from within a Listener. This is what I am trying accomplish:

I created a Blog plugin and because the Homepage will be complex I wanted to attach an event to **beforeRender** for the **Pages** controllers and then return a list of 200 items that can be 'consumed' in different views and elements(ie. `/src/Template/Pages/display.ctp` and `/src/Template/Element/latest_blog_items.ctp`)

So far I have created this

```
// Blog.config/bootstrap.php
<?php

$homepageListener = new HomepageListener();
EventManager::instance()->attach($homepageListener);
```

And in the  same plugin

```
// Blog.src/Event/HomepageListener.php
<?php

namespace Blog\Event;

use Cake\Event\Event;
use Cake\Event\EventListenerInterface;
use Cake\Core\Configure;
use Cake\ORM\TableRegistry;

class HomepageListener implements EventListenerInterface {

    public function implementedEvents() {
        return [
            'Controller.beforeRender' => 'getBlogItems',
        ];
    }

    public function getBlogItems(Event $event) {
        if ($event->subject()->name == 'Pages') {
            $fBlogItems = TableRegistry::get('Blog.BlogPosts')->find('all')->order(['BlogPosts.created' => 'desc'])->limit(200)->toArray();
            // This works, but I didn't want to do it this way
            Configure::write('fBlogItems', $fBlogItems);

            // My desired solution would be creating a variable similar to what is done in Controllers
            // ie. $this->set('fBlogItems', $fBlogItems);
        }
    }

}
```

I have not figure out how, if possible, I can set a variable (ie. `$this->set('fBlogItems, $fBlogItems)` and ensure it is available in my Template files.

Is this even possible or advisable? 
Does it break MVC?
Is there a better way?

Comment: I think a cell might suit this case better https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/cells.html

Comment: @burzum I was trying to avoid using cells in an attempt to make it more streamlined. From what I understand from cells, I would have to create method for various sections, ie. latestItems(), headlineItems(), etc. Based on the fact that what I am creating is a standalone plugin, I figure I would just pass the variable to the App's templates and have them deal with the team. In addition, it can be complicated when it comes getting items from DB that are not duplicated.

Comment: I was hoping EventListener would be a better solution for this case.

Comment: I wanted to basically make 1 call to DB pull 200 items and let the various sections of the Homepage consume it. Which will prevent duplicates when items apply in two sections. ie. latestNews and breakingNews

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$event->subject()` is your controller instance so just use `$event->subject()->set()`.

Comment: Get out of here! This is a brilliant solution and fits perfectly into I was looking for. Thank you so much!